# Space (View) is not working in ListItem Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-listview, space

I've got a ListActivity with a custom Adapter. This adapter uses the following list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/checkbox_content_description"
            android:src="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked"
            android:background="@layout/transparent_background"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_product_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll1">

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/filler_space"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/actv_search_product"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:digits="0123456789.,-" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the Adapter's getView-method I've added the following piece of code:

```
// Change the width of the Filler-Space to match the Image
// and leave the height as is
Space space = (Space) view.findViewById(R.id.filler_space);
space.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), space.getMeasuredHeight()));
```

This gives the following result at first:

[image]

When I change the Visibility of my second LinearLayout (ll2) to VISIBLE, it gives the following result:

[image]

What I want instead is:

[image]

As it seems the Space-View width isn't changed at all.. While I know for fact that the getView methods are successfully called thanks to Log-messages and other things I do in the getView method.

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

PS: When I use View instead of Space I have the same result. Never used Space before, so I thought it might have to do something with that.

---

Solution thanks to Demand's option 4:

```
// Since we can't access Measured widths and heights before the View is completely loaded,
// we set up an Observer that will be called once the ListItem's layout is ready
ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
if(observer.isAlive()){
    // In order to access the view in the onGlobalLayout, it needs to be final, so we create a final copy here
    final View v = view;
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        // This will be called once the layout is finished, prior to displaying it
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Space space = (Space) v.findViewById(R.id.filler_space);
            // Change the width of the Filler-Space to match the Image and leave the height as is
            space.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), space.getMeasuredHeight()));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set width and height if your space to wrap_content. It's mean that space will have width as their children, but there is no children and you have width = 0. It's not about space, it's about layout measuring in android.
When you call your code:

```
Space space = (Space) view.findViewById(R.id.filler_space);
space.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), space.getMeasuredHeight()));
```

Your imageView havn't measured yet and return width = 0. It will measured later before drawing. In getView() in adapter you only create views, but measuring, layout and drawing will be later.

You have several ways to fix it:

1. set width of your space in dp, instead of wrap_content.
2. using relative layout instead of three linear layouts.
3. Use TableLayout.
4. add GlobalTreeObserver and getMeasuredWidth() at right time.
5. Post your runnable to view's handler to get width after drawing.

I think the best ways is 2 and 3, because 4 and 5 will cause measuring several times.

Comment: Thanks, I went for option 4 and added a ViewTreeObserver to get the ImageView's MeasuredWidth. I've added the solution-code to my question as reference to others.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen ok, but keep in mind, that it's not the best perfomance solution. You will measure and layout twice for each row. If you will scroll fast you list it may be critical. I suggest to find a little time for refactoring and make RelativeLayout later =)

Comment: Hmm, I used to have a RelativeLayout when I started at this View, before I added the EditTexts, but then I had problems with the Name-TextView, which should fill the space in between the other two and should have ellipses (three dots) in case it's too long. But will put a TODO in the code and when I'm going to optimize everything I'll try it again.